# Oauth Provider Symfony2

Tags: symfony, oauth, bundle

I'm learning how to develop with Symfony2 and I would like to create a RESTful Oauth server (No a Oauth client for Facebook,twitter etc...).
I saw FOSOAuthServerBundle but it doesn't look like a Oauth provider...
Could you recommend me a good bundle for that?

Comment: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/1.1.1/README.md, it seems to provide a Oauth connexion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best oAuth server provider I used id for symfony2 is FOSOAuthServerBundle.
It will provide all Oauth functionality for you.
The configuration is little bit tricky,

[This blog](http://blog.logicexception.com/2012/04/securing-syfmony2-rest-service-wiith.html) will help you to configure the oAuth Server by using FOSOAuthServerBundle .